# Put null value in dynamic list with jquery

Tags: jquery, null

I've a function to make a dynamic list.

```
$sel = $('<select id="Addlst">').appendTo($td);
$.each(TableStruct[post].Liste, function (ind, value) { 
    $('<option ' + (ind == 0 ? 'selected="selected "' : "") + ' value="' + value + '">').html(ind).appendTo($sel); 
});
```

I use value like integer. In 99.9% of cases, I've no problem. But when I've null value (it's for ranking product) My root is null in DataBase. 
Then when I ask $('#Addlst').val(); ... I've "null".
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the solution

```
 value="' + ((value==null)?'':value) + '"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need a validation check for your `value` parameter. if the value is `null` then no `option` is created. (if I understood right)

Try the following

```
   $sel = $('<select id="Addlst">').appendTo($td);
    $.each(TableStruct[post].Liste, function (ind, value) {
      if(value!="null"){ 
        $('<option ' + (ind == 0 ? 'selected="selected "' : "") + ' value="' + value + '">').html(ind).appendTo($sel); 
       }
    });
```

Comment: I need this value. It's ranking like a tree. It's to classify product. I need to put some rank to root value

Comment: I think I need change method, to put value stop use concat with +. Better usr method like I use for text : html(...) but how do this?